# bean entityManagerFactory not found after updating spring boot from version 2.1.4 to 2.2.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Everything works if I use the spring boot version 2.1.4 but if I upgrade it to 2.2.5, I get the error entityManagerFactory not found. I have tried clearing the .m2 folder and using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` but it doesn't work. It works fine till spring boot version 2.1.13 but I am unable to update it to version 2.2.

Here are my dependencies in pom.xml.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/*bo*/*.java,
        **/*request*/*.java,
        **/*response*/*.java,
        **/*logging*/*.java
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring boot rest api annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- common functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- aspect oriented programming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Unit testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field xyz in class name required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
"}
```

Comment: You get a stacktrace when that happens, add it to your question. Currently there is way too little information to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum Done.

Comment: Try re-running your application with --debug. Which will give you a stacktrace with more information. Also I would suggest using 2.2.5. RELEASE (instead of 2.2.0) and please add your `application.properties`.